# Django date to javascript at the template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

What would be the easy way of achieving such below? selected_date comes from django context as a python date :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selected_year = {{ selected_date|date:"Y" }}
    var selected_month = {{ selected_date|date:"m" }} - 1;
    var selected_day = {{ selected_date|date:"d"}}
    var selected_date = new Date(selected_year, selected_month, selected_day);
    alert(selected_date);
</script>
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I've had a lot of success with the isoformat function in python:

```
var selected_date = new Date("{{ selected_date.isoformat }}")
```

Comment: That's definitely a lot simpler than what I proposed! +1 (removing my answer)

Comment: isoformat doesn't work for me in safari or firefox (fine in chrome and IE).

Comment: Is this even timezone aware?

Comment: The python method will return timezone data if available and Javascript is fully capable of parsing this.

Comment: What would be the nicest or simplest way to apply this if I pass a list of dates in Django to convert to a list of JavaScript dates?

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer may generate an incorrect date depending on locale.

In FF console:

```
>>> n = new Date('2011-01-01');
Date {Fri Dec 31 2010 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)}
```

It's therefore preferable to pass Y,m,d integers to the Date constructor.

I use a template filter to generate the date constructor:

```
@register.filter(name='jsdate')
def jsdate(d):
    """formats a python date into a js Date() constructor.
    """
    try:
        return "new Date({0},{1},{2})".format(d.year, d.month - 1, d.day)
    except AttributeError:
        return 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 8):

I was using this and realized Android was returning 'Invalid Date' when parsing it - I think it's stricter than the desktop Webkit. I am instead using the following, which seems to work:

```
new Date('{{ talk.start_datetime|date:"D, d M Y H:i:s"}}'),
```

More on JS date parsing is here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: This won't work on locales other than English. Use the isoformat above!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your date in JS, you will want to use the escapejs filter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selected_date = new Date({{ selected_date|escapejs }});
    alert(selected_date);
</script>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs

Answer (score 0):

Since other approaches are not timezone aware, you can simply use the [Django's built-in Template Tag **widthratio**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#widthratio) to convert python's seconds to javascript's milliseconds.

```
new Date({% widthratio selected_date|date:"U" 1 1000 %}
```

Comment: What is going on here?