# Django: Pass a list of dates to JavaScript in template for Chart.js

Tags: javascript, django, datetime, django-templates, chart.js

I'm using Django as backend and want to draw a line plot using Chart.js with dates on the x-axis.
I'm trying to pass the dates as `datetime.date`s from my view:

```py
def eval_time_series(request):
    context = {
        'dates': [datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(1, 8)]
    }
    return render(request, 'app/eval_time_series.html', context)
```

Now the question is how to process and use these dates in the JavaScript code generating the line plot. This is what I currently have:

```html
div id="container">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // trying to convert to JS dates here
    var labels = [];
    {% for d in dates %}
    labels.push(new Date("{{ d.isoformat }}"));
    {% endfor %}

    var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: "Car Speed",
                data: [0, 59, 75, 20, 20, 55, 40],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                   type: 'time'
                }]
            }
        }
    };

    window.onload = function () {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
    }
</script>
```

So basically, I am trying to apply the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5077395/2745116) to an array of dates by iterating over all dates, converting them, and adding them to the JS array.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work: No chart is displayed and the console is flooded with errors.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have the same problem as me. Try removing

```js
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        type: 'time'
    }]
}
```

from options. I'm having it where my chart won't render if I include the scales option. If I leave it out, the chart renders, but the dates are the fully-formatted date and time. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242381/scales-option-appears-to-break-chart-js-graph) is my post for comparison.