# django model Date time filed not been accessable to javascript

Tags: django-models

I am trying to implement a date time countdown in my django project using script. But I want it to be dynamic, so I created a model for passing the date time field but got `NaNd "NaNh NaNm NaNs"` instead of the actual date and time passed from the model.

**Model**

```py
class Event(models.Model):
    end_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

**View**

```py
def event_detail(request, event_id):
    event = Event.objects.get(pk=event_id)
    current_datetime = timezone.now()
    return render(
        request,
        "nysc_landing.html",
        {"event": event, "current_datetime": current_datetime},
    )
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```js
<script>
        // Function to update the countdown timer
        function updateCountdown(endTime) {
            var now = new Date();
            var distance = new Date(endTime) - now;

            // Calculating remaining time
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            // Displaying the countdown timer
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
                + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

            // If the countdown is over, display a message
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
            }
        }

        // Fetching the end datetime from backend
        var endTime = "{{ event.end_datetime }}";

        // Update the countdown timer every second
        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            updateCountdown(endTime);
        }, 1000);
    </script>
```

Comment: Try adding pipe to format datetime you get from model: `var endTime = "{{ event.end_datetime|isoformat }}"`. If that doesn't work try `end_datetime.isoformat`.

Comment: When you console.log `event.end_datetime`, what do you get?

Comment: this end_datetime.isoformat actually worked. thanks

Comment: it was actually meant to work but had some minor error in my url

Comment: Great. I wrote up an answer with some additional infos so you can consider accepting it and up-voting it if it's useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, one of the possible solutions is converting datetime to `iso` format:

```
var endTime = "{{ event.end_datetime.isoformat }}"
```

Maybe it's even better to parse year, month, day... and pass them to `Date` constructor. It depends on your needs, if `iso` format works for you, great.

You can read up more about this topic on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076319/django-date-to-javascript-at-the-template), although answers are more than 10 years old so don't really know if something changed.

*Also, little off-topic, consider using `let` and `const` instead of `var`, it may be better.